# XPATH use AND OR combination

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I got the following HTML code:

```
<div><h6>abc/h6><p>date</p></div>
```

I can successfully find this element with selenium based on text. Now the problem is that `<h6>` can contain different words like "def" OR "ghi". How can i add a OR in the following XPATH?
With only AND this is working:

```
"//div/p[contains(text(),'date') and preceding-sibling::h6[contains(text(),'abc')]]"
```

Now with AND & OR have tried without success

```
"//div/p[contains(text(),'date') and preceding-sibling::h6[contains(text(),'abc') or preceding-sibling::h6[contains(text(),'def')]]"
```

also this without success

```
"//div/p[contains(text(),'date') and preceding-sibling::h6[contains(text(),'abc' or 'def')]]"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of the predicate for `h6`, test whether it contains 'abc' `or` contains 'def':

```
//div/p[contains(text(),'date') 
  and preceding-sibling::h6[contains(text(),'abc') or contains(text(),'def')]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the `<p>` predicate in `and` with `<h3>` either with text *abc* or *def* as follows:

```
//div//p[contains(.,'date')] [//preceding-sibling::h6[contains(.,'abc')] or //preceding-sibling::h6[contains(.,'def')]]
```